# Android Studio opens a fragment but doesn't change bottom navigation menu state

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio-3.0

I have one button that let's me change the fragment and it does that successfully. I open new fragment but the bottom navigation menu doesn't change it's style. It's simple bottom navigation menu and because it is, when you select fragment you are currently looking at it makes that fragment's text on the bottom bigger and icon becomes bigger too.
That's the problem here, it doesn't change the menu.

```
goButton = (ImageButton) SOMEView.findViewById(R.id.go_button);
    goButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()   {
        public void onClick(View v)  {
            System.out.println("Started");

            AppCompatActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
           ((MainActivity) mainActivity).bottomNavigation.findViewById(R.id.nav_info).callOnClick();
            Fragment nextFragment = new INFOFragment("second");
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, nextFragment );
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });
```

INFOFragment:

```
public class INFOFragment extends Fragment {

public String state;
@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public INFOFragment(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(state.equals("first")) {
        System.out.println("info");
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_info, container, false);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("second state started");
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_another_view, container, false);
    }
}}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public BottomNavigationView bottomNavigation;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bottomNavigation = findViewById(R.id.bnavigation);
    bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navigationListener);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new INFOFragment("first")).commit();
    bottomNavigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_info);
}

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navigationListener =
        new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                Fragment selectedFragment = null;
                switch(item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.nav_another_view:
                        System.out.println("vid ovo");
                        selectedFragment = new ANOTHERVIEWFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_info:
                        System.out.println("v2id ovo");
                        selectedFragment = new INFOFragment("prvi");
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_some_view:
                        selectedFragment = new SOMEFragment();
                        break;
                }
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,selectedFragment).commit();
                return true;
            }
        };}
```

Answer (score 0):

Step1: Create a constant on MainActivity like this

```
int prev_nav_item = 0;
```

Step 2:

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navigationListener =
        new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                Fragment selectedFragment = null;
                switch(item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.nav_another_view:
                        System.out.println("vid ovo");
                        selectedFragment = new ANOTHERVIEWFragment();
                        prev_nav_item = 0;
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_info:
                        System.out.println("v2id ovo");
                        selectedFragment = new INFOFragment("prvi");
                        prev_nav_item = 1;
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_some_view:
                        selectedFragment = new SOMEFragment();
                        prev_nav_item = 2;
                        break;
                }
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,selectedFragment).commit();
                return true;
            }
        };}
```

Step 3: Make a function to change bottom menu position in main activity

```
public void selectBottomMenu(final int position) {
        Handler uiHandler = new Handler();
        uiHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                bottomNavigation.setCurrentItem(position);
            }
        });
    }
```

Step 3: Update bottom menu position from each fragment like this in onResume()

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ((MainActivity) mActivity).selectBottomMenu(0); //change value depending on your bottom menu position
    }
```